# Insertion sort using linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

(1) You will implement only insertion sort, and (2) you will use a linked-list to store the long integers, instead of using an array for storage. Consequently, your sorting will have to be performed on a linked-list.

My code is as follows.

```
Node *Insertion_Sort(Node *sublist) {
//Initialize`enter code here`
Node *dummy_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
dummy_node->next = NULL;

Node *prev_node = sublist;
Node *curr_node = sublist->next;

Node *head = prev_node;

Node *temp_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
while(curr_node->next != NULL){
    if (prev_node->value < curr_node->value) {
        //advance the pointers
        prev_node = curr_node;
        if (curr_node != NULL) {
            curr_node = curr_node->next;
            printf("Advancing prev=%ld curr=%ld\n", prev_node->value, curr_node->value);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //swap
        temp_node = curr_node;
        prev_node->next = curr_node->next;
        curr_node->next = prev_node;
        // Advance
        prev_node = curr_node;
        curr_node = curr_node->next;
        head = prev_node;
    }
}
//curr_node->next  = NULL;

return head;
}
```

But it is only partially working. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Define "it's only partially working".

Comment: Like @dornhege said, what is your current output?  What do you think the problem area is? Some additional information makes answering your question much easier.

Comment: That you're allocating *anything* in the sort routine of this is questionable. that you're using `malloc()` to do it in a C++ program is *highly* questionable. I don't recall anything in insertion-sort that mandated temp storage except for the swap, and since you're using linked lists, the only thing you should be swapping are pointer values, not nodes.

Comment: `Node *dummy_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));` will not compile in C++ without a cast

Comment: I am learning data structure.i need to sort a list of numbers .for that i have to use  insertion sort and also use a linked list to store long integers.

Comment: partial means i am not getting a complete sorted list.only first two numbers are repeating

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to allocate any space for nodes. Wiki link for [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). You're probably supposed to use the second pseudo code example (where the part before i is sorted, and you're inserting into the sorted part by removing and inserting a node):

```
for i ← 1 to length(A)
    x ← A[i]
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > x
        A[j] ← A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    A[j] ← x
```

replacing the inner while loop to just scan for where A[i] needs to be inserted. Note if A[i] is greater than all of the sorted list, then the inner loop doesn't iterate, j == i, and A[i] doesn't need to be moved (so just continue with the outer loop).